# binary search tree - get heaviest path algorithm c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

using a binary search tree I need to add to a vector all int elements of the heaviest path of the tree.
for example I have 20,7,6,9,11,21
the values that should be added to the vector would be 20 ,7,9,11
I have written the implementation of the calculation of the heaviest path, but I don't know how to change it so the right elements will be added to the vector:

```
int Tree::maxBranch(Node* node){
    if(node==NULL)
        return 0;
    int leftSum=node->data+maxBranch(node->left);
    int rightSum=node->data+maxBranch(node->right);
    if(rightSum>leftSum){
        return rightSum;
    }
    return leftSum;     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written does not keep track of the branches it's followed at all - it only gets the sum.

You should change the function to take an `std::vector<int>&` as an argument (note the `&`, for a reference type, since you need to effectively return two values).

Call it with an empty vector.

Before the line where you do the recursive call on `node->left`, you should *save* the original vector as, for instance, `std::vector<int> vec_left(input_vector)` and `std::vector<int> vec_right(input_vector)`. Then pass the two copies down to the recursive calls.

Now, in the code, just before `return rightSum`, you should have a `vec_right.push_back(node->id); input_vector = vec_right;`. Just before `return leftSum`, you should likewise have a `vec_left.push_back(node->id); input_vector = vec_left;`. In English, you keep the path that was made by the branch which had the highest sum, and discard the other one.

Comment: @mary One more note: make sure to add the node's ID to the return in the base case (before `return 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty:

```
int Tree::maxBranch(Node* node, vector<int>& vec, bool add){
    if(node==NULL)
        return 0;
    int leftSum=node->data+maxBranch(node->left, vec, false);
    int rightSum=node->data+maxBranch(node->right, vec, false);
    if (add)
        vec.push_back(node->data);
    if(rightSum>leftSum){
        if (add)
            maxBranch(node->right, vec, true);
        return rightSum;
    }
    if (add)
        maxBranch(node->left, vec, true);
    return leftSum;     
}
```

Comment: That's very dirty - you call `maxBranch` twice for every step along a considered branch.

Comment: @Borealid - true, it may still be more performant than your solution due to less memory allocations.

Comment: The ideal solution would use an explicit stack with a single vector for path being explored, but I didn't want to bother describing it.